postgreSQL 16 install password doesnt work to connect to the server (MacBook Pro)
I recently installed Postgresql 16, during the installation one window came up showing that I need to put two same passwords for postgres, so I just put 4 numbers and hit next,
Here is the image

when I opened pgAdmin4, It was askign me to enter the password for the user 'postgres', I wrote the same exactly password as the setup password, but it didnt work

so I uninstalled postgreSQL, i deleted the data folder as well.

then I installed again, from the  setup password, i put 12345, then finished installation, lastly I opened pgAdmin, now I write the same password (12345), i doesnt work as well.
i dont know what to do, i'm really confused, it's my first time downloading postgres, I have good familiar with oracle, but I really need to install this and use it, is this setup password only for postgres user or what? why can't I just deleted the first server (I think its postgres) user and make a new one, does it asking me to put a new password for every user or not?

Try this: I forgot the password I entered during PostgreSQL installation  (P.S. I know you did not forget it, but the answer there should help you get it working)

I'm experiencing the exact same issue on Windows.

I can invite you to create bug here: Where to Report Bugs  (registration required.)
